# Is all traffic to and from a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) from Amazon Web Services (AWS) encrypted?

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know it would be encrypted with a physical VPN used in conjunction with the VPC, but is it encrypted in the absence of a physical VPN? The [AWS Security Whitepaper](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/pdf/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf) alludes to the fact that traffic is encrypted when they say on page 23 that "Amazon EC2 instances running within an Amazon VPC inherit all of the benefits described below related to the host OS, guest OS, hypervisor, instance isolation, and protection against packet sniffing." I'm thinking that the protection against packet sniffing at the end is a reference to encryption. But even though it says "benefits described below", "sniffing" or "sniff" is never mentioned again in the paper. If not all traffic is encrypted, what would be a good way to go about encrypting certain traffic? Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you talking about the public facing subnets or private subnets or both? Because I don't think the public facing ones would be encrypted

Comment: stick with ssh or https on your in/out traffic and you're golden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Protection against packet sniffing' may or may not allude to encryption (it could also refer to network isolation, etc.), but if you're not using a VPN then you need to use some other *explicit* method of encryption, for example SSL (HTTPS) or SSH.

If you're connecting to a remote Unix-based system to copy files back and forth (for example), SSH is a solid encrypted transport mechanism. If you're loading web content then SSL is the obvious example. FTP can be done over either SSH (SFTP) or SSL (FTPS), with acronyms I can only assume were deliberately designed to be confused with each other.

If you open up a telnet connection or HTTP to the VPC, your traffic is unencrypted.

Comment: Good answer. I might add that their statement "protection against packet sniffing" probably refers to other instances on the same host. The comment is probably not encryption related.